# Saving the State of an Application using App-V or some other type of Virtualization Technology

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, windows-server-2012, app-v

I have an application that I would like to be able to create "snapshots" of (sort of like you might do with a virtual machine).  Basically I would like to be able to allow the user to do a bunch of processing on the application and be able to take snapshots at various points that he could come back to later.  I'm not even sure if App-V would be a technology I could use for this.  If not, how would I go about doing something like this?

Further Clarification:  There was a legacy application which didn't have the functionality built in to save the current state of a project to the file system.  I was thinking of using this as a temporary workaround until a replacement application became available.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. The only thing I can think of for this would be snapshotting the whole machine (assuming a VM), or using the App-V streaming process to capture each point, which might make replayability a problem.

Of course, this entirely assumes that the application state is self-contained on a single system. If it's talking to remote SQL or a webservice, etc (if it depends on something else), then if you can't *also* snapshot the remote entity, you can't do this at all.

Give us more background please : What is the problem that you're actually trying to solve?